# AUCTex in WSL cannot find TeX Live in Win

Tags: auctex, wsl

When trying to compile/ pdf-preview a tex-file, minibuffer spits out:

```
ERROR: AUCTeX cannot find a working TeX distribution. 
Make sure you have one and that TeX binaries are in PATH environment variable
```

Setup:

1. AUCTex (up-to-date version from ELPA) via:

Win 10 --> wsl (1) --> Debian 11 (+ VcXsrv for GUI) --> Emacs (from the official 'bullseye'-repository)

2. `c:/texlive/2022/bin/win32/`  (full install)

Paths for TeX Live and Ghostscript in the Windows environment-variables are correctly set: working fine in Emacs under Win 10 and also Cygwin.

Is there anything else I would have to do for AUCTex to find TeX Live under Windows?

By all means I would like to avoid a second 7GB-install of TeX Live in WSL.

Update:

When in the WSL Linux-console I type: pdflatex.exe, it says: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex) restricted \write18 enabled."

It can therefore be safely assumed that WSL1 does read the path correctly? Why then can not Emacs-AucteX find it. May "restricted" have anything to do with it? Or that it says "pdfTeX", instead of pdfLateX? After another several days of digging in the dark, I am on the brink of giving up.

Update 2:

1. I created a helloworld.tex-file in wsl-emacs: no compiling, just saved it to the default folder.
2. I quit wsl-emacs and in wsl-debian console typed: pdflatex.exe helloworld.tex
3. This actually created the according helloworld.pdf.

So the wsl/ windows-texlive connection is definitely alive and working.

Therefore I'm still wondering: Why is this not possible in wsl-emacs, why can auctex not find texlive?

Another observation, if relevant: If 1) in wsl-emacs I create the helloworld.tex and not just save it, but also, unsuccesfully, try to compile ('latex' or 'pdflatex') it  2) exit emacs and in wsl-debian console type pdflatex.exe helloworld.tex 3) it now denies permission:

c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)pdflatex.exe: helloworld.aux: Permission denied

Update 3:

After a good sleep, the probable solution to the problem seems, to me at least, so obvious that I'm surprised am the first to come up with it... ;)

When I tell auctex in wsl-emacs to compile/ 'pdflatex' helloworld.tex, it by default tries to do this within *wsl*. So it is bound to complain, as there is no TexLive in wsl.

The right and as we've seen above working command to compile/ 'pdflatex' the file in TexLive *Windows* is pdflatex.***exe***.

So it seems all I would have to do is tell auctex to execute pdflatex.exe, instead of just pdflatex.

Does this make any sense? If so: now how/ where in auctex can I change the default command accordingly?

Thanks!

Update 4: Still no success.

Nobody knows? In the auctex-command settings I've tried by changing command 'pdflatex' to 'pdflatex.exe', but auctex still can not find TexLive.

Maybe I have to give and/ or mount the full Windows TexLive somehow, somewhere?

Comment: Related question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56078/

Comment: Does your emacs comes from wsl or Windows? If it is from the former, maybe installing a Windows version of emacs.

Comment: Emacs, as stated, is in wsl. Actually I installed wsl, just so I can use Emacs under linux...